# Paypal Cart Requiring Login

Tags: php, paypal, shopping-cart

I have a website which will sell products online, and I'm going to use a PayPal shopping cart to do so. I want to require people to login in order to place orders, and have successfully integrated Facebook such that this can be done in one-click.

However, the PayPal cart, as I can see, has no way of supporting "needs to be logged in" to make a purchase, as the actual cart itself is stored on PayPal's servers. It's a very easy method of taking payments, and required almost no setup. Unfortunately it has this restriction.

I'm currently using "Express Checkout". I could keep the cart on my server, stored in some sort of cookie, then use "Website Payments Standard" to accept a single payment for the gross amount of the cart.

Would this be the best solution, or does PayPal offer some sort of solution whereby I can somehow tell it if a user is logged in?

Having a situation where the "Add to Cart" buttons are hidden if the user isn't logged in won't work because they could open pages in tabs, log out, then add things to their cart without being logged in.

I'm using cakePHP if anyone knows of a particular extension or anything that could help.

Answer (score 0):

Using any PayPal payment method the buyer was to be redirected to PayPal in some form - a full redirect, an iframe, or minibrowser - so they can log into their account, select a billing method, and then return to your site or complete the payment.

Using Express Checkout buyers are returned to your site where you can complete the payment on your own site through the DoExpressCheckoutPayment call.

You can use Reference Transactions to rebill a successful transaction but you need to have first set up a billing agreement through Express Checkout. If a billing agreement wasn't created you can't bill the buyer again without requiring they log into PayPal.